# Jenkins not detecting Mercurial repository

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, ubuntu-14.04

I'm currently trying to setup a new CI/CD system based on Ubuntu 14.04 using Jenkins and Mecurial as my SCM. (Tortoisehg ui)

I've been through this all before using Windows which was pretty straight forward however i'm getting a bit stuck with getting Jenkins to recognise my repositories.

I've tried all sorts of combinations for paths and what not but nothing seems to be working.

So just to explain my setup - I'm using a NAS as the central repository of which I've cloned locally and am using Tortoisehg as my interface.

Any help i'd really appreciate!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Will. From what I see in your Jenkins configuration, you asked to clone a repository located on your local disk: `/home/adpbuild/projects/gmii_v6.5_test`. Are you sure the repository exists at the given path?

Did you try maybe to configure **where** Jenkins should clone the repository? As you can see in the first screenshot, it will always clone it in `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MII 6.5 Autobuild`, I don't think you will be able to change it without changing the global configuration of Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by changing the way in which i was 'cloning' one of the repos we use even though what i had was fine for pulling and pushing to our server. Turns out i had to create an empty repository first before then using TortoiseHg to direct to my server and then clone, this solved my issue!

Thanks to Boris for pointing me in the right sort of direction.